# Why the Select box is not changing the value while dynamically adding the Row to the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Hi I have the code where i am just adding one row dynamically.But the problem is in the next row inside the select box the value are not changing .Then how to achieve this using Jquery Mobile.Below is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.add").on('click', function() { // brace missing
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var $clone = $tr.clone();
        $clone.find(':text').val('');
        $clone.find(':checkbox:checked').prop('checked', false).val('N');
        $clone.find('#preferred').val('N');
        //$clone.find('#phntype').selectmenu("refresh", true);
        $tr.after($clone);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <form name="form" id="form" method="post" action="%bind(:11)">
        <label></label>
        <!--/Phone Table Information -->

        <table border="1" id="phone" width="100%" name="phone">
            <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Country Code</th>
                <th>*Phone</th>
                <th>Preferred</th>
                <th>Add/Delete</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <select name="phntype" id="phntype">
                            <option value="BUSN" selected="">Business</option>
                            <option value="CAMP">Campus</option>
                            <option value="CEL2">Cellphone2</option>
                            <option value="CELL">Cellphone</option>
                            <option value="FAX">FAX</option>
                            <option value="HOME">Home</option>
                            <option value="OTR">Other</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label id="Streetlbl">Street:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Street" name="Street" value="" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label id="Streetlbl">Street:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Street" name="Street" value="" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label id="Streetlbl">Street:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Street" name="Street" value="" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type='button' value='+' class='add' />
                    <input type='button' value='-' class='delete' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p></p>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you have included `jquery` twice and `.live` is **deprecated** since `jquery 1.7`. use `.on` instead!!

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in your `js` and I would like to suggest to add `class` to your `select` instead of `id` since you are cloning the entire controls and appending it to `DOM` and having similar `id`s in the `DOM` is against the `DOM` rules and its bad practice. So just add class to your `select`

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/5js0hjqt/)**

```
$(document).on('change','.phntype',function(){
        $(this).prev('span.phntype').text($(this).find('option:selected').text()); 
});
```

Add `class`, remove `id`

```
<select name="phntype" class="phntype">
```

Comment: _value of select box should be empty one_ in the sense you don't want any value to be selected when it is cloned??